# Is it possible to fire event on addition or removal of child element to parent DivElement instance in GWT?

Tags: javascript, dom, gwt

I have an instance of content editable GWT DivElement to which I am attaching some elements dynamically. Can I fire event each time when I add a child element to parent DivElement instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord) to do what you need.

You set up an Observer on your DivElement and observe `childList` mutations. In `MutationRecord` you can get `addedNodes` list.

There is no native GWT support for MutationObserver, so you need to use JSNI:

```
private native void addListener(Element elem) /*-{
    // create an observer instance
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            if(mutation.type == 'childList') {
                // mutation.addedNodes contains nodeList of added nodes
                $wnd.alert('Nodes added');
            }
        });
    });

    // configuration of the observer:
    var config = {
        childList : true
    };

    // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    observer.observe(elem, config);
}-*/;
```

Just call `addListener(div);` on your DivElement.